# ERROR: invalid GeoJson representation

Tags: postgresql, json, spatial, postgis, geojson

the GeoJSON Spec show,

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

But when I wrap that in a call to [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html), like this,

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($${                                                                                                                          
  "type": "Feature",                                                                                                                                   
  "geometry": {                                                                                                                                        
    "type": "Point",                                                                                                                                   
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]                                                                                                                       
  },                                                                                                                                                   
  "properties": {                                                                                                                                      
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                    
}$$);
```

I get the error,

> ERROR:  invalid GeoJson representation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs on [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html)

> `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` works only for JSON Geometry fragments. It throws an error if you try to use it on a whole JSON document.

This means you'll want to cut out just the value from the geometry in your GeoJSON document,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom)
FROM ST_GeomFromGeoJSON($${                                                                                                                          
  "type": "Point",                                                                                                                                   
  "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]                                                                                                                       
}$$) AS geom;

     st_astext     
-------------------
 POINT(125.6 10.1)
```

*ℹ [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) is the inverse of  [`ST_AsGeoJSON`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) (which only produces the `geometry` section of GeoJSON document.)*

Answer (score 1):

Modern PostgreSQL + PostGIS accepts JSONB, the best datatype for this job.

```sql
WITH json_load AS (
 SELECT $${
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
 }$$::JSONB j
)

SELECT 
   j->>'type' AS type,
   ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(j->'geometry') geom,
   j->'properties' AS props,
   (j->geometry->coordinates->1)::real AS longitude
FROM json_load;
```

You need only the `geom` column, all other columns are illustrative of the [richness of JSONb expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), and how is easy to cast to *text* datatype, to *real*, etc.

---

Note. At server-side, in the *json_load* part,  you can use `pg_read_file('/tmp/myFile.geojson')::jsonb` to read files. Use something like `chmod 666 /tmp/myFile.geojson` before. A GeoJSON collenction of geometries can be exploded by  `jsonb_array_elements` function.

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you